# JQuery: Append to table head

Tags: jquery, ajax, append, html-table, head

So I'm trying to append data from the Url to the head of the table. The data called from the URL is a string list. So as you can see I'm trying to go through each value in the list and then append it to the head of my table, 'data'.
But when I run the code nothing is appended. I know the data is going in because the window alert is displaying each of the strings.

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://..../api/Dynamic?table=table1',
        dataType: 'Json',
        success: function (tableResults) {
            var count = 0;
            $.each(tableResults, function () {
                window.alert(this);
                $('#data th:last-child').append('<th><a id="count">' + this + '</a></th>');
                count++;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<table id="data" border="1" align="center" width="95%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you... appended a th to a th. that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tableResults is an array of string you can use directly the each parameters and avoid the count variable like in the following snippet (use after instead of append because the new th elements must follow and not be child of the last th):

```js
//
// if thead does not exist
//
if ($('#data thead').length == 0) {
  $('#data').append($('<thead/>'));
}

$.each(['email', 'address', 'country'], function (index, value) {
  if ($('#data th:last-child').length == 0) {
     //
     // if there are no th
     //
    $('#data thead').append('<th><a id="count' + index + '"</a>' + value + '</th>');
  } else {
    $('#data th:last-child').after('<th><a id="count' + index + '"</a>' + value + '</th>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="data" border="1" align="center" width="95%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What if the table head is empty?

Comment: Yes it's similar to your array, and I don't get an error

Comment: @JacksonSentzke Does my snippet work? I updated it. Could you test again and let me know? Thanks

Comment: I think `$('#data thead tr').append(...)` would be enough to cover both cases (whether or not the `thead` is empty), no need for `if` statement.

Comment: @Artur Filipiak You are right. The problem is related to a comment: If the thead or th does not exit how can I create them? I understand your point but my answer was based on how you can create an element if it does not exist.  Looking the question and answer now it is clearly redundant....  In any case thank you so much.